# ASP MVC 2 submit на разные события

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, submit

Возник такой вопрос как правильнее реализовать.

Имеем форму, в которую пользователи вносят некие данные, данных много и у пользователей есть выгружаемая с другой системы html с частью данных (напрямую обратится к этим данным невозможно).
Задача облегчить жизнь пользователям.

Появилась мысль сделать следующее, при загрузке файла отправлять его и текущую модель данных на сервер, где
1) парсить файл, 
2) вычленять из него данные,
3) обновлять модель,
4 )возвращать пользователю форму с обновленной моделью.

В итоге додумался до такого, на форме две кнопки с submit и разделение их по атрибутам (выискал [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479946/asp-net-mvc-4-form-with-2-submit-buttons-actions))

т.е. имеем

```
public class HttpParamActionAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (actionName.Equals(methodInfo.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return true;

        var request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        return request[methodInfo.Name] != null;
    }
}
```

так же имеем два POST метода

```
[Helpers.HttpParamAction]
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult UploadFromFile(MeasurementValues model, System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
     // ... 
     return View("CreateOrEdit", model);
}

[Helpers.HttpParamAction]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(MeasurementValues model)
{
      // ...
      return RedirectToAction("Index", new { DepID = mv.DepartmentId });
}
```

форма в view объявлена как

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="form-actions">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <button type="submit" name="UploadFromFile" value="UploadFromFile" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
</div>

<fieldset class="form-horizontal">
    <legend>@ViewBag.ActionName <small>@Model.Date.ToShortDateString(), @ViewBag.Workshift, @ViewBag.Department, @ViewBag.RoleID</small></legend>
    <input type="hidden" value='@Model.Date.ToShortDateString()' />
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DepartmentId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.WorkshiftId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Username)
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" style="width:100%;">
        <thead class="header">
            <tr>
                <th>п/п</th>
                <th>Наименование</th>
                <th>Значение</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Values)
    </table>

    <p>Пояснение</p>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RemarkId)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Remark)
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
        @Html.ActionLink("Отмена", "Index", new { DepID = Model.DepartmentId }, new { @class = "btn " })
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

собственно, работает все кроме передачи файла в System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase file, туда упорно приходит null.
Вопрос как заставить это работать, или ткните носом в правильный путь :)